# BootStrap 3 Login page design

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, authentication, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have to design a webpage like attached screenshot. How can I develop that like in any resolution heights and widths will be adjusted automatically?

[image]

Thanks

Small Code I have written...

```
  <head>
<title></title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="assets/custom/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="assets/bootstrap/js/respond.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container marginleft0px paddingleft0px">
    <div class="row paddingleft0px">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4  paddingleft0px paddingright0px">

            <img src="images/image1.png" alt="image loading" style="width: 100%; height: 502px"
                class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8  paddingleft0px paddingright0px">
            <div class="row">

                <img src="images/Slides/slider.gif" alt="image loading" style="width: 100%; height: 332px"
                    class="img-responsive" />
            </div>
            <div class="row  paddingright0px">
                <img src="images/image2.png" class="img-responsive" alt="image loading" style="width: 100%;
                    height: 171px" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="assets/bootstrap/js/jQuery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/bootstrap/js/respond.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have no idea where you are going with your code above. Here is the general outline for a responsive layout along your red lines:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div>Carousel or slider code...</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <img src="" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div>Content, logo or whatever...</div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is my code is wrong? When I followed your code, left and right side white space is coming. In between image1 and slider image  I am getting space.. If I want to target large screens? You are using col-md... Can you pls let me know what is the logic?

Comment: First, please post the code you are using for reference. The container will set a max-width (default 1170px) with white space on both sides. Simply remove the container if you want your page to be full width. In regards to spacing inside of the grid: there is spacing (gutters) in the grid. This is done by applying padding to the col-xx.  You can manually remove it through css. Post your code and let's see what you've got so far...